# For SharePoint Search Server Express 2010, Why is Rank Returned from Scope() Always Default (100000000)

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, search-server-2010

### SharePoint Search Server Express 2010, Why is Rank Returned from Scope() Always Default (100000000)

**I need to know what I need to do differently in terms of configuration changes, etc. within Search Server Express to have this rank issue resolved.**

I have crawled a very large number of files using **Search Server Express 2010** and when I select rank from Scope using QueryText (for a given search term), I always get the same **rank** for all returned items, **100000000**.

Because of this, order by rank makes no difference. **I need the rank to reflect the number of occurrences of the particular term in each file**. Rank used to vary (and be correct) when SSE 2010 was installed on Windows Server 2008 R2, but with Windows Server 2016 the rank is always 100000000.

For example,
If File A has "oil" 1 time, File B has "oil" 3 times and File C has "oil" 4 times, the current order returned from the select below, with the order by, is:
**File A, File B, File C**
(because that is the order in which the files were crawled, and each file unfortunately returns the rank of 100000000 for each file).
The order I need to have returned, with the order by, is:
**File C, File B, File A**
(with File C having a larger rank than B, and B having a larger rank than A, so that the order by rank can order things correctly).

**I call method Query of the built in SOAP Service that comes with Search Server Express 2010 (_vti_bin/search.asmx) and pass the following:**

```
<QueryPacket><Query><QueryId /><OriginatorId /><Context>
<QueryText type='MSSQLFT' language='" + language + "'>
   SELECT rank, Filename, path, description FROM SCOPE()
   where (path like 'file://" + RepositoryFiles + "/%.xml')
    and (contains(All, '"oil*"')) 
    order by rank desc
 </QueryText>
 </Context>
 <EnableStemming>true</EnableStemming>
</Query></QueryPacket>;
```

I very much appreciate insight that can lead to a resolution of this issue.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/282871/for-sharepoint-search-server-express-2010-why-is-rank-returned-from-scope-alw